# pydantic Multi-field comparison

Tags: fastapi, pydantic

I would like to do A>B validation when I have the following pydantic class, do you know how to do that?

```
class Test(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: int
```

Comment: There's some further whole model validation under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75644811/use-validator-in-pydantic-model-for-date-comparison) with an answer from yours truly that implements field comparison validation with a compact base class that can be derived from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use validator method from pydantic:

```py
from pydantic import validator

class Test(BaseModel):
    a: int
    b: int

    @validator('b')
    def ab_validation(cls, b, values, **kwargs):
        if 'a' in values and b > values['a']:
            raise ValueError('B is greater than A')
        return b
```